# Check in on or checking on?

Tags: word-choice

I got this email from a friend, who was concerned about the heat problem (which I complained to her weeks ago) in my apartment. Do I thank her for "checking in on me" or "checking on me"?

Answer (score 7):

They are [both correct](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=checking%20on%20me&word2=checking%20in%20on%20me) phrases. Apparently "[checking on me](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=checking%20on%20me,%20checking%20in%20on%20me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,checking%20on%20me;,c0;.t1;,checking%20in%20on%20me;,c0)" has an older lineage, but in modern English, either is appropriate (in the US anyways).

"Checking in", it could be argued, has a connotation of the speaker being physically present, as in someone coming to visit or a parent or nurse looking into your room. However, the distinction is small enough to be irrelevant — no one I know would fault you for using it in a letter.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't use either, but instead I would say thanks for thinking of me, or give an update and say thanks for asking.

Comment: That though ignores the fact that they want to thank the person not just for thinking of them, but for the extra effort in checking on/checking in on them.