# "Check" or "check in on"

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

This verb, "to check", really confused me. Here's what I have found so far:

> "check" in the meaning: *to examine something to see if it is correct, safe or acceptable*
> [(source: Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/check_1?q=check)

***Check** your work before handing it in.*

> "check in" [US] to find out or report the status of someone or something
> especially as part of a regular pattern of communication or
> monitoring (often followed by **on** or **with**)
> [(source: Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/check%20in)

*We access our work email on our phones, catch up on messages during our commutes and even when we're out at lunch, **check in on** work before bed—some of us feel like we have to just to be good employees.*

https://youtu.be/dQVzxFh9yBc?t=957 (15:57)
https://youtu.be/0_dlGmwMywY?t=39 (0:39)

What is the difference between the two verbs with the meaning "examine things" in all these cases? Is it possible to replace "*check in on*" with "*check*" and vice versa in the examples above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context, you are dealing with two *quite separate* verbs:

**To check** *transitive*<sup>1,</sup> = to ascertain if something is correct.

**To check in** (phrasal verb) *intransitive* = to arrive for the purpose of contact. ("in" is an adverb.)

To introduce their complement, intransitive verbs need a preposition, which has a noun phrase as its object:

I checked in(adv.) on(prep.) John(NP).

<sup>1,</sup> **To check** is, technically, ambitransitive, i.e. an object may not appear but can always be implied.

Comment: Dear *Greybeard*, one of the meanings "to check in" is the same as "to check", even though the words are separate their meaning might be the same (example from M-W above - **check in on** work before bed).  Or am I wrong here? Is it possible to figure out when to use "to check" and when "to check in (on sth)"? For instance: *"After I'd finished the exam, I **checked** my answers for mistakes"* or *"After I'd finished the exam, I **checked in on** my answers for mistakes"*. Which one is fit better in this example?

Comment: *check in on work before bed* = contact your place of employment before bed. -- *check **the** work before bed* = to inspect the work that has been done before bed.*

Answer (score 2):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/check-in) makes this sense of **check in** clear:

> *check in* [contact]:
>
> to contact someone by making a phone call, short visit, etc, usually
> in order to make sure there are no problems or to tell them that there
> are no problems:
>
> - *My son checks in regularly with me when he's travelling.*

M-W goes straight to the purpose of making contact, which is unhelpful.

It does however add the useful 'often used with *on* or *with*'.

Typical examples:

- *I'll check in on my grandad on the way home to see if he needs anything from the shops.*
- *I'll check in with the lab to see if the new phials have arrived yet.*

....

**Check** is easily researched.

Comment: However, [check in on the sleeping child](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dollhouse_ebook/brBHEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22check+in+on+the+sleeping%22&pg=PT102&printsec=frontcover) is more "check on" than "make contact/communicate with"

Comment: Dear *Edwin Ashworth*, the meaning is clear for me. What I couldn't  get is **the distinction between** "check" and "check in on". Here's the example from the video that I attached: *"This is gonna be my last episode before I vacate this home office for a couple of weeks and go into another room. But that doesn't mean that I won't be **checking in on** things and strategizing some plans for next year"*. Why this person did not use just a verb "to check"?

Comment: ... Because the speaker/writer is emphasising that they will be **_visiting_** the home office (and virtual usages, various media, are not in general excluded when one uses 'check in') to do the checking. The 'in' is spatial (or pseudo-spatial) as with 'pop in to see', 'look in on'.

Answer (score 0):

**check in on (someone or something)**

> To actively monitor the security or safety of a person or thing.
>
> *Before I meet you at the mall, I need to check in on my grandmother to make sure she's feeling OK.*
>
> See also: *check, on* [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/check+in+on+(someone+or+something)#:%7E:text=To%20actively%20monitor%20the%20security,See%20also%3A%20check%2C%20on)

> To "check in on" someone means to visit, call, or write to them to
> find out how they're doing:
>
> *When someone new joins the team, I like to check in on them at least once a day.* [phrasemix.com](https://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/check-in-on-someone)

---

> Another related method is graduated extinction: the parent will
> **check in on** the child in progressive increments such as 1, 2, 4, 8 min, etc. [Raman Malhotra; *Sleep or Sleepiness: Clinical Approach to the Sleep
> Patient*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sleepy_or_Sleepless/fB0_CgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Another%20related%20method%20is%20graduated%20extinction:%20the%20parent&pg=PA188&printsec=frontcover)

> The therapist explains that they will call to **check in on** how the
> child is doing a few weeks after treatment has ended. [Douglas Nangle
> et al. *Treating Internalizing Disorders in Children and
> Adolescents*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Treating_Internalizing_Disorders_in_Chil/7WqVCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22check%20in%20on%22%20the%20children&pg=PA301&printsec=frontcover)

> When you do log in to **check in on** your family and friends, don't
> click on pop-ups, articles, or posts that are detracting from your
> intention for social media use. [Jimmy Casas et al. *10 Perspectives
> on Learning in Education*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/10_Perspectives_on_Learning_in_Education/Z0jWDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22to%20check%20in%20on%22%20means&pg=PT78&printsec=frontcover)

See also [Check in on or checking on?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139060/check-in-on-or-checking-on)