# "Check on" or "check in on"

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

> "check on" in the meaning: to make sure that there is nothing wrong with somebody/something
> *(source: Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)*

*I'll just go and **check on** the children.*

> "check in on" in the meaning: to make sure that there is nothing wrong with somebody/something
> *(source: Phrasemix)*

*She needed a friend. When she returned to school, I began to **check in on** her every day to make sure that she wasn't hurting herself.*

https://youtu.be/mgQRAuspuC4?t=126 (2:06)
https://youtu.be/3dDTlKj2n44?t=1262 (21:02)

What is the difference between the two verbs with the meaning "examine someone" in all these cases? It is unclear. In what situations is "*check in on*" used and in what ones "*check on*"?

P.S. I know that there was [such](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139060/check-in-on-or-checking-on) question, but I still do not understand the difference.

Comment: There's _check up on_ as well! As the answers to the other question say, there is no clearly-defined difference.

Comment: Yes, I've heard this one, but *"check up on sb"* means *"to control sb"* (to make sure that somebody is doing what they should be doing - Oxford Learner's Dictionaries). As its meaning is different I decided not to include this one in my question.                                                    So you want to say that **"check on"** and **"check in on"** may be used as 100% synonyms?

Comment: Personally, I would use _check in on_ to refer to going _into_ someone's house or room to make sure they were OK, but it appears that not everyone makes that distinction.